# setImmediate() function not being called after process.nextTick() function

Tags: node.js, event-loop, libuv

For this snippet:

```
const foo = [1, 2];
const bar = ['a', 'b'];

foo.forEach( num => {
  console.log(`setting setImmmediate ${num}`);
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log(`running setImmediate ${num}`);
    bar.forEach(char => {
      console.log(`setting nextTick ${char}`);
      process.nextTick(() => {
        console.log(`running nextTick ${char}`);
      })
    })
  });
} )
```

The output is

```
$ node scratch.js                   
setting setImmmediate 1
setting setImmmediate 2
running setImmediate 1
setting nextTick a
setting nextTick b
running setImmediate 2
setting nextTick a
setting nextTick b
running nextTick a
running nextTick b
running nextTick a
running nextTick b
```

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick)

> the nextTickQueue will be processed after the current operation completes, regardless of the current phase of the event loop.

As I understand, `process.nextTick()` will add to the current event's `nextTickQueue`, and executed immediately after the current event, no matter what phase the event loop is in.

Shouldn't the output therefor be the following?

```
setting setImmmediate 1
setting setImmmediate 2
running setImmediate 1
setting nextTick a
setting nextTick b
running nextTick a
running nextTick b
running setImmediate 2
setting nextTick a
setting nextTick b
running nextTick a
running nextTick b
```

Answer (score 1):

> the nextTickQueue will be processed after the **current operation** completes, regardless of the current phase of the event loop.

I misunderstood the [event loop documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#process-nexttick) in thinking that "current operation" means the *currently processing **event***, where in actually it means *the currently processing **phase***.

From Danial Khan's [What you should know to really understand the Node.js Event Loop](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c)/:

[image]